# Need help working with nested elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a script that's meant to auto-truncate blockquotes over a certain size and add a "Read more" link to them. The catch is that the block quotes are nested inside of each other, which has made things a bit tricky. I've got the script working fine for single-level block quotes, but when faced with nested blockquotes it ends up wiping more information than I want it to.

What I'd like it to do is this:

1. Examine the children of the parent element to find the parent's first blockquote child
2. Check if this blockquote contains an image in its first paragraph. If it does, clone the first AND second paragraphs of this blockquote. If it doesn't, just clone the first paragraph.
3. Check and see if this blockquote contains any other blockquotes. If so, clone all of its descendant block quotes.
4. Combine the cloned paragraphs of the parent blockquote and all of the cloned blockquote descendants (if applicable) into one variable (we'll call it cloneCon).
5. Replace the html of the parent blockquote with the contents of the variable cloneCon.
6. Append the read more link to the parent blockquote.

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```
var post = $('#post_two_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce');
var markup = $('<body>').append(post.html()); // temporary container

markup.children('blockquote:first').each(function() {
    var original = $(this).prev('p').children('a').attr('href'); 
    var viz = '';
    if ($(this).children('p:first').find('img').length > 0) {
        var viz = $(this).children('p:lt(2)').clone();
    } else {
        var viz = $(this).children('p:first').clone();
    }

     $(this).html(viz).append('<p><a href="'+original+'" class="tumblr_blog">Read More</a></p>');
});

post.html(markup.html());
```

Everything inside the `markup.children` each function is what I'm having trouble with. Here's what the HTMl I'm working with looks like:

```
<p><a class="tumblr_blog" href="http://example.org">user#1</a>:</p>
<blockquote>
    <p><a class="tumblr_blog" href="http://example.org">user#2</a>:</p>
    <blockquote>
        <div>
            <p><img alt="image" height="340" src="" /></p>
            <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sit amet velit nibh. Aliquam leo libero, pellentesque eget fringilla eget, pretium eu purus. Pellentesque a neque at arcu fermentum volutpat. In et dolor ligula, et aliquam odio. Sed sagittis fermentum massa, vel tempus neque adipiscing nec. Nunc posuere commodo orci, ac imperdiet odio malesuada eget. Aliquam pharetra pretium faucibus. Sed erat urna, laoreet quis ornare quis, fermentum quis lacus. Vestibulum a interdum nisi. Proin hendrerit orci non neque dignissim feugiat. Vivamus pretium pretium nunc, ut dapibus augue ullamcorper at. Suspendisse ac est vel velit vehicula accumsan quis vel turpis. Pellentesque eros velit, ullamcorper ac tempus sit amet, placerat quis magna. Sed ipsum nibh, convallis at tempor sit amet, vehicula vitae mauris. Aenean rutrum, lorem vitae suscipit tempor, libero lorem porta diam, a semper nulla erat in mi. Morbi leo lacus, placerat id hendrerit vitae, semper id tellus.</p>
            <p><a class="tumblr_blog" href="http://example.org">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
    </blockquote>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor.</p>
    <p>Consectetur Adipsing Elit.</p>
    <p>I used to wonder what friendship could be.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Thank you for your help!

Edit: I got it. I simplified my execution by simply telling the script to clone the parent blockquote in its entirety, then trim out the desired number of child paragraphs from the parent blockquote.

Comment: 7. What color were the engine driver's eyes?

Comment: Please post your edit also as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I simplified my execution by telling the script to clone the parent blockquote in its entirety, then trim out the desired number of child paragraphs from the parent blockquote. That way I don't need to check if there are child blockquotes or not; they're cloned automatically.